# Выпадающее меню справа

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, хочу сделать выпадающее меню как на картинке, чтобы при наведении на элемент списка появлялись другие вложеные списки. Сейчас имею меню без вложенности такого вида: https://jsfiddle.net/8wkzL14e/

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content>li {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Smth</li>
      <li>Smth</li>
      <li>Smth</li>
      <li>Smth</li>
      <li>Smth</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

li>ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content>li {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Smth sub
        <ul>
          <li>Smth sub
            <ul>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Smth</li>
          <li>Smth</li>
          <li>Smth sub
            <ul>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
              <li>Smth</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Smth</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Smth</li>
      <li>Smth</li>
      <li>Smth</li>
      <li>Smth</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```